# How to upload images to server and restore them using Tinymce

Tags: asp.net-core, tinymce

I am trying to build a medium clone with `asp.net core` and `TinyMCE`. Tiny has an init property called `image_upload_ur`l. This property has `'/WriteArticle'` value and this page has an OnPost method that can answer post requests. But I am taking `HTTP 400 bad requests` when I am adding images to the editor. What should I do?

```
tiny initialize options:
automatic_uploads: true,
images_upload_url:'/WriteArticle',
images_upload_path:'/uploads',
```

WriteArticle.cshtml.cs method:

```
public IActionResult OnPost()
{
    Console.WriteLine("OnPost");
    try
    {
        var file = Request.Form.Files[0];
    var uploads = Path.Combine(_environment.WebRootPath, "uploads");
    var filePath = Path.Combine(uploads, file.FileName);

    using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
    {
        file.CopyTo(fileStream);
    }
    return new JsonResult(new { location = "/uploads/" + file.FileName });
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    return BadRequest(new { message = ex.Message });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

400 (Bad Request) response because the framework expects the `RequestVerificationToken` as part of the posted request.The framework uses this to prevent possible CSRF attacks. If your request does not have this information, the framework will return the 400 bad request.

Or you can bypass the checks by adding the IgnoreAntiforgeryTokenAttribute to the relevant PageModel class:

```
[IgnoreAntiforgeryToken(Order = 1001)]
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    public void OnPost()
    {
    }
}
```

You can have a look at [Request Verification](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/security/request-verification#opting-out) to know more.